# Unknown device or simulator UDID

Tags: appium

Appium does not find my sim. Here is the Appium error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'CC518D0B-7B20-4E93-94B6-CEA304D19AC'

I have the sim running, and have verified the UUID is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and all the existing answers didn't help. I was able to finally get it working by doing the following:

```
- Install JDK.
- Set Java_Home path in Appium settings.
- Try another simulator and then switch back to the simulator I was initially aiming for.
```